# jade mixin arguments with bracket throw an syntax error

Tags: pug

i make a mixin like this( for knockout virtual elem binding)

```
mixin ko(condition)
  != "<!-- ko "+condition+'-->'
  // /ko
```

but when i want call

```
+ko('if:condition()')
```

it throw an error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

maybe a ast parse issue but now i suppose a way to work arount with it?

Answer (score 1):

all right i found an ugly way to deal with it

```
+ko("if:condition(\u0029")
```

Comment: there's a lot of this type of stuff in jade that has soured me.  right now I'm spending more time working around jade than it's helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better solution:

```
mixin ko(bind)
    | <!-- ko #{bind} -->
    if block
        block
    | <!-- /ko -->
```